# Как в css сделать элемент с вертикальным позиционированием - fixed, a горизонтальным relative?

Tags: html, css

Как в css сделать элемент с вертикальным позиционированием - fixed, a горизонтальным relative?

Что-то наподобие:

```
horizontal-position: relative;
vertical-position: fixed;
```

**Обновление**

Есть сайт http://www.slivki.by/, нужно сделать данное действие с хеадером.
Причина: на девайсах с маленьким экраном при увеличении видна только кнопка входа в хеадере, т.е. нормально поиском пользоваться нельзя.
Т.е. по вертикали он должен быть прилипшим, а по горизонтали - нет.

Comment: А как вы себе это вообще представляете?) Покажите конкретно задачу.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так не делать.

Если уж совсем-совсем нужно, то в фиксированном блоке шириной 100% можно разместить блок с overflow: auto, а в нём уже колдуете.

Но ещё раз повторю: лучше так не делать. Вспомните, что вы не только делаете сайты, но и пользуетесь ими. Вспомните, насколько неудобны все эти фиксированные элементы. И не делайте так.